# Redux saga fails to catch actions after they hit the reducer

Tags: redux-saga

I'm trying to implement redux saga for a client but I can't get saga to catch the action after hitting the reducer. My saga never seems to fire so I'm not getting what I expect after I call the "DATA_FETCH_REQUESTED" reducer action.

The result I expect is: for my saga to fire and the errorMessage variable in my redux store to contain the fetched data or if fetch fails, the the error message.

The result I'm getting is: my saga does not fire and the errorMessage variable in my redux store always ends up containing the string "### saga failed to catch this action ###" (which it should but should then be corrected by my saga's action which never happens)

My concern here is that the saga middleware never starts up properly. I've put print statements in my saga and I never see them in my console which seems to confirm my theory. Any help would be greatly appreciated. See code below:

**This is my root saga file:**

```
    function fetchData() {
        // fetches data
    }

    function* callFetchData() {
        try {
            const data = yield call(fetchData)
            yield put({ type: "DATA_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", data: data })
        } catch (e) {
            yield put({ type: "DATA_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message })
        }
    }

    function* fetchDataSaga() {
        yield* takeEvery("DATA_FETCH_REQUESTED", callFetchData)
    }

    function* rootSaga() {
        yield [fork(fetchDataSaga)]
    }

    export default rootSaga
```

**This is my reducer:**

```
    const initialState = {
        errorMessage: null,
    }

    const dataReducer = (state = initialState, { payload, type }) => {
        switch (type) {
            case "DATA_FETCH_REQUESTED": {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    errorMessage: '### saga failed to catch this action ###',
                }
            }
            case "DATA_FETCH_SUCCEEDED": {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    errorMessage: payload.data,
                }
            }
            case "DATA_FETCH_FAILED": {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    errorMessage: payload.errorMessage,
                }
            }
            default: {
                return state
            }
        }
    }

    export default dataReducer
```

**This is my index.js file:**

```
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import App from './App'
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
    import rootReducer from './redux/rootReducer'
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
    import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
    import rootSaga from './sagas/rootSaga'

    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

    const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

**UPDATE:**

It looks like I just forgot to wrap my rootSaga's yielded value in the all() method from the 'redux-saga/effects' library. Changing it to the following:

```
    function* rootSaga() {
        yield all([fork(fetchDataSaga)])
    }
```

There wasn't an error because it was a logical problem not a syntactical one

Answer (score 1):

> I can't get saga to catch the action before hitting the reducer.

Redux saga can't do that. Redux saga is designed to send actions to the reducer first, and then to sagas afterwards.

If you need an action to be handled by a saga first for some reason, then i'd recommend splitting it into two actions: The first action is not listened to by any reducer, so even though it goes to the reducers it has no effect. Then the saga gets it, and it turns around and dispatches the second action. That second action is the one that the reducer handles.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense but then why do I never get my fetch data? Based on what you're saying I just need to wait for the fetch to finish but no matter how long I wait I never see my fetched data or console.logs I put in my saga. Doesn't that mean I implemented something wrong?

Comment: I would think so, yes. From the code you're shown i'd expect it to temporarily set the state to "### saga failed [etc]", then once the fetch succeeds or fails, to update the state again. So i would delete the part of the reducer that's listening for "DATA_FETCH_REQUESTED" so you don't have that temporary state, and then wait.

Comment: Possibly. If you can share the fetchData function i'll look it over. If you pull up developer tools and look at the network tab, do you see the request being made? Also, can you confirm if the saga starts running (ie, stick a console.log at the beginning of callFetchData)?

Comment: Right now all it does is return a string. So there shouldn't be a delay

Comment: I did try putting console.logs but they never fire. Meaning yes, it is possible that saga never starts running but I don't understand why

Comment: here's what is currently my fetchData function: ```return '### saga successfully caught this action ###'```

Comment: I've updated my post to reflect these efforts to debug

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `DATA_FETCH_REQUESTED` action? It seems that you expect the saga to listen to your reducer. The reducer is the final destination in this flow, hence wont fire any action and just update its state.

The correct flow should look like so:

You need to call an action from within your code to send a request for fetching the data

```
// Action: to be called from within your component
export function fetchData() {
    return { type: "DATA_FETCH_REQUESTED" };
}
```

Then the saga will execute once it recognize `DATA_FETCH_REQUESTED` action

```
// Saga: handles DATA_FETCH_REQUESTED action call 
function* callFetchData() {
    try {
        const wizards = yield call(fetchData) // <--- did you mean data instead of wizards?
        yield put({ type: "DATA_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", data: data })
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({ type: "DATA_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message })
    }
}

// Saga: listen to DATA_FETCH_REQUESTED actions
function* fetchDataSaga() {
    yield* takeEvery("DATA_FETCH_REQUESTED", callFetchData)
}
```

Then the reducer will updated accordingly

Good luck

Comment: That happens in my app.js on render. I didn't include that but the call looks like this ```props.wizardsFetchRequested()```

Comment: Here's what the actions look like:
```export const wizardsFetchRequested = () => ({ type: 'WIZARDS_FETCH_REQUESTED' })

export const wizardsFetchSucceeded = wizards => ({ type: 'WIZARDS_FETCH_SUCCEEDED', payload: { wizards } })

export const wizardsFetchFailed = errorMessage => ({ type: 'WIZARDS_FETCH_FAILED', payload: { errorMessage } })```

Comment: Clearly my redux code is working or else I would have a null value in my errorMessage variable. So the problem has to be something else

Comment: @AlecHorwitz - You only need 1 action: `Here's what the actions look like: export const wizardsFetchRequested = () => ({ type: 'WIZARDS_FETCH_REQUESTED' })`
when you call this action `props.wizardsFetchRequested()` then `callFetchData` saga will start executing. If it fails then it put `DATA_FETCH_FAILED` with error message, otherwise it put `DATA_FETCH_SUCCEEDED` with the data.
The reducer has these cases covered, so you don't need the other 2 actions for success/failure. As you can see, you are using `put` in your saga which is identical to call an success/failure action.

Comment: @AlecHorwitz - also note, that you are using `data` instead of `wizards` when you called `fetchData`. You want to pass the result to your reducer. Hence use `data: wizards`

Comment: Yeah, sorry that wizard variable is a hint at what this code base is for. I intentionally made it generic to avoid any legal issues with the client.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didn't seem to do what I wanted. I'm still seeing the same outcome.

Comment: @AlecHorwitz - I also suggest you to store the data In a data field rather than errorMessage within your success reducer. And I think your setup is OK

Comment: I have posted this https://codesandbox.io/s/z6y22y357p a while ago, It will help you understand my point. (Good Luck)